# Did the Perseverance sky crane kick up more dust than expected?

Tags: mars, perseverance, dust

The video of the Perseverance landing showed the rover descending into a cloud of dust kicked up by the landing rockets. This is not surprising, but I always had the understanding that one of the reasons for the sky crane approach was to avoid precisely that. I realize there were other reasons. [This Wikipedia entry gives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Science_Laboratory#Entry,_descent_and_landing_(EDL)) a good overview, and [this news article](https://www.space.com/16889-mars-rover-curiosity-sky-crane-landing.html) actually doesn't even mention the dust issue as a main reason.

So, I'm curious - was there more dust than expected? And was avoiding dust spray (say, avoiding even worse dust than they got) a significant engineering consideration?

Comment: Avoiding plume/surface interaction was a definite concern; a meteorological sensor on MSL was damaged by debris thrown up from the surface https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-19338870

Comment: I think this is a question that can really only be answered by someone with access to information about what they expected unfortunately (that doesn't make it a bad question, although it may make it hard to answer).  Certainly making the landing *survivable* was a significant consideration.

Comment: I think the goal was to avoid damage be big debris. Dust should not have been too big a concern (except for navigation cameras on the crane) for the rover as it's not solar powered. It seems, that the goal of "no damage by debris" was not 100% successfull tough.